# \includegraphics -- file not found, even when in same directory

Tags: graphics

Here's the preamble:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
```

... And here's the call to `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{n6d.png}
```

The error on the log:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `n6d.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.39 ...aph & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{n6d.png}
                                               & \includegraphics[scale=...
```

Typing "H" just puts it into draft mode.

The file 'n6d.png' is located in the same folder as the `.tex` file. I've tried putting just 'n6d' as the filename, but still have the same problem. Here's the command I'm calling to compile the PDF:

```
"C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" -output-directory "D:\Documents\School\Math3\Worksheets\3" "D:\Documents\School\Math3\Worksheets\3\wksht3_sols.tex"
```

There are other files in the `.tex` file that are having the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: There are many Questions about input paths. For instance this one might be interesting for further reading http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89247/input-file-folder/89285#89285

Comment: \includegraphics{ image.png } failed for me. \includegraphics{image.png} then succeded. I ran into trailing / leading whitepace problem.  I need ten reputation without association to answer so -> unfortunately for everyone I put my answer in a comment.

Comment: Can't post an answer due to reputation limitations. Another subtle cause may be an empty file - for me, pdflatex was giving this error when i've tried to include existing file, which had zero size due to transmission error.

Answer (score 26):

I was having this problem too but have figured it out -- I know this is an old thread, but since the question might come up in searches for people with current problems (it came up in mine), I'll say how I fixed it.

If using MiKTeX, even if your figure file is in the same directory as the TeX file you're working with, you have to refresh the file name database every time you add files into this folder. So do this:

1. open MiKTeX Settings / Options;
2. Roots tab: check that the folder with the files in it is one of the Root paths;
3. General tab: Maintenance: Refresh

This solves it for me.

Comment: Threads are never old on stackexchange if you have good information to share. This is not the typical stupid forum managed by typical stupid people ;-)

Comment: I'm having this problem, but I use TeXLive, and refreshing the FNDB didn't help me. Very frustrating since everything was working smoothly until today.

Answer (score 18):

Its not important that the image file is in the same directory of the `tex` file. It should be in the working directory where you launch the `pdflatex` command.

For example, if you run:

```
cd ~/bar
pdflatex foo/baz
```

the PDF file should be in the `~/bar` directory rather than the `~/bar/foo` directory.

Use the command `\graphicspath` to set a different path.

**added:** this is what happens when you run `pdflatex` from a command line. If you are using an integrated editor, you should dig into the options to see how the editor chooses the working directory into which to run the `pdflatex` command. I think that usually the working directory will be choosen as to be the directory containing the main source file.

Comment: What do you mean by "working directory where you launch the 'pdflatex' command?"

Comment: @alanH for example when compiling on a continuous integration server, the command is executed in a directory you-don't-know-where that just happens to be the working directory for the server at that time. On your own system this is probably just the directory your tex file is in.

Comment: The `pdflatex` command is running in the same directory but still not found. I'm on `macos`

Answer (score 15):

You can set the path of your figures by adding

```
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}} %Where the figures folder is located
```

To your preamble.  Of course, `{./Figures/}` is actually the path where the figures' folder is located.

Also, you may want to try not using `wksht3_sols.tex` as your file name (due to the `_`).  Change it to something like wksht3sols.tex

Try doing these two things to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks.. If any one got this problem after an upgrade to Mac Yosemite, then the use of two curly brackets in \graphicspath will solve it.

Comment: This was my issue; I had underscores in the file name. That seems kind of obnoxious. Do we know what the reason for that is?

Comment: I had underscores but they weren't the problem. I tried `myfile.eps` and `/myfile.eps`, but not `./myfile.eps`. You either need to include the current directory (dot) in the beginning of the `\includegraphics` path or set the `\graphicspath` first. :facepalm:

Answer (score 10):

I also had this problem. The source of the error was (for me), that the file for the image I wanted to include was registering as having no file-extension (even though it really IS a `.png` file, and opens like one)! But it listed in the terminal as having no file-extension (for some strange reason).

I just renamed it to `file.png` instead of `file`, and of course everything worked fine from there!

So maybe check if your image file actually does "exist" before you stress about which directory LaTeX is checking and so on.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Exchange way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me after I add these lines

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran to the same problem today but the cause was different from any of the answers listed here: I was using the package underscore *and* including pictures containing an underscore in the filename.

### Minimum (non)working Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4cm]{picture_1.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with

```
pdflatex MWE.tex
```

yields

```
LaTeX Warning: File `picture_1.png' not found on input line 9.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `picture\unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \hskip \
z@skip \T1\textunderscore \discretionary {-}{}{}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip 1.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.9   \includegraphics[height=4cm]{picture_1.png}
```

### Solution

Rename picture_1.png to picture-1.png.

### Side note

Interestingly, removing the line

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

leads to a different error message

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \discretionary 
l.8   \includegraphics[height=4cm]{picture_1.png}
```

([I am not the first to notice it](http://muhammadgolamkibria1095.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/missing-number-treated-as-zero.html)) and only after pressing Enter complains about picture_1.png not found.

Comment: The underscore with the usual category code is *not* the problem. But package `underscore` makes the underscore active and adds hyphenation support in text mode that breaks its use in file names. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/underscore/underscore.pdf) of `underscore` describes workarounds in section "Deficiencies". Thus option `strings` (`\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`) works as `\string` for `_` in `\includegraphics[...]{picture\string_1.png}`.

Comment: For me `xelatex` always included files with `_` but `lualatex` could not.