# Using a bash script to compile, then Image in same directory not found. Mac OS 10.15.7, pdfLateX (texlive), function \includegraphics{image}

Tags: graphics, pdftex, texlive, includegraphics, bash

As the title suggests, I am putting an image into my pdf document using the \includegraphics command. It works, and puts my output main.pdf in the same directory as expected.

Here's where my question starts, I have this "compile" script written by this guy here [bilalakil.me](https://bilalakil.me/getting-started-and-productive-with-latex-basictex-on-os-x-terminal) which generates a log and uses mv to move the main.pdf to an "output" folder.
I can live without the script, but it would be cool if someone had a quick solution to this.

Compile script:

```
mkdir output
rm -rf .tmp-compiling
mkdir .tmp-compiling

cd .tmp-compiling
cp ../main.bib .

pdflatex ../main.tex
bibtex main
pdflatex ../main.tex
pdflatex ../main.tex

cp main.pdf ../output

cd ..
rm -rf .tmp-compiling
```

Doing it this way, suddenly the images no longer work.

Expected output: [image: Image Diagram working]
Using compile script output (not working as expected):
[image: Missing Image]

I've already looked through this discussion and tried everything : [Stack Exchange Image not Found \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95617/includegraphics-file-not-found-even-when-in-same-directory)

Proof that my .tex file and .png image are in the same directory:

[image: Directory image]
A paste from the error log:

LaTeX Warning: File `orbitd1.png' not found on input line 16.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `orbitd1.png' not found: using draft setting.

Here is the tex document named "main.tex" :

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Homework 5}
\author{Kleiner Warden}
\date{date}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\includegraphics{orbitd1.png}


\end{document}
```

Long story short, I found a script that was helpful but it breaks the usage of \includegraphics{image}.

Comment: all paths are relative to the current directory of the tex process, not relative to the file, so your image would need to be in .tmp-compiling.  It is almost always better to cd to the directory with the document and use `pdflatex file` rather than use a path such as `pdflatex ../file` on the commandline.

Comment: I've modified my script to the following : `mkdir output
rm -rf .tmp-compiling
mkdir .tmp-compiling

cd .tmp-compiling
cp ../main.bib .
cd ..
pdflatex main.tex
cd .tmp-compiling
bibtex main
cd ..
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex

cp main.pdf output

rm -rf .tmp-compiling` It now works.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: why not do bibtex at top level as well you are just runningthat in .tmp-compiling and it would seem you would need to copy the .aux file there and copy the generated bbl file back

Comment: I haven't yet tested a document using bibtex with this bash script.  What problem would be caused if I keep it the way it is?

Comment: I can't see how it works at all either as posted in the question or as I guess you mean in the comment (hard to read the second one with no line breaks)