# pdflatex specifying output directory doesn't find images in subdirectories

Tags: graphics, pdftex, include, output

I have the root of my project in a directory called `tex`. This directory contains several subdirectories for different chapters:

```
$ tree
.
└── tex
    ├── root.tex
    └── sub
        ├── chapter.tex
        └── image.png
```

The files contain:

**root.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\graphicspath{{sub/}}
\input{sub/chapter.tex}

\end{document}
```

**sub/chapter.tex**

```
\includegraphics{image.png}
```

When I `cd tex` and then build the project via `pdflatex root.tex` everything works fine. However when I want to build the project from somewhere else via the option `-output-directory` it doesn't work. When I'm in the parent directory of `tex` and run `pdflatex -output-directory tex root.tex` it doesn't seem to find the image:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `sub/image.png' not found.
```

However from `man pdflatex` I read:

> **-output-directory directory**
>   Write  output  files in directory instead of the current directory.  Look up input files in directory first, the along the normal search path.

The second part suggests that `directory` is also used to search input files relative to it. `sub/image.png` exists in `tex` so I don't see why it can't find the image.

Comment: You should not add the ending of the image in `\includegraphics`. I'm not sure whether that is **the** problem, but it might at least be **a** problem.

Comment: No it won't work. "the normal search path"  is relative to the directory were you run pdflatex, only `tex` will added additionally. (I never use --output-directory, imho you get more problems than gains.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The man page reads "Look up input files in directory first [...]", so I expect every path in my tex files to be relative to the specified directory. However it can't locate the image. If you say `-output-directory` is error prone, what would you use instead to build a latex project from another directory?

Comment: I would never  build from another directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try including files with `\input{../tex/sub/chapter.tex}`, so go up one directory and then down the same one. This should assure that files are being sought relative to the main tex file instead of in the directory from where the `pdflatex` command is being run, who knows where that is...

Be sure to include the `.tex` extension! In my case that was a break point, it didn't work without extension (the way you normally include files).

More info on this topic at [Input file folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89247/input-file-folder).

PS If you work on a continuous integration server like Travis you can first change the working directory and then file includes work fine.